# Contar letras repetidas em python

Tags: python, lista, dicionário

Estou criando uma função em python que conta quantas vezes a letra o aparece em cada elemento da lista, e meu resultado precisa de ser uma lista.

Gostaria de saber onde estou errado.

```
nomes = ['Joao', 'Roberto', 'Pedro', 'Antonio']

def contador(nomes):
  vogal = 0
  letraO = 'o'
  for letra in nome:
    if letra in letraO:
      continue;
    else:
      vogal += 1
  print('Quantidade de vezes que a letra o apareceu: ', vogal)

contador(nomes)
```

Comment: Parece um erro de lógica, você não declarou a variável `nome`, ela não existe no escopo do método `contador`. Como o código está errado não avaliei o algoritmo para saber se existem outros problemas. :-/

Comment: Além disso tem um ponto-e-virgula após a declaração do comando `continue`.

Comment: O for tem q percorrer a lista `nomes`. Ex.: `for nome in nomes`. E dentro do for vc pode apenas usar o count em `nome`. Ex.: `vogal += nome.count(letraO)`

Comment: Se o resultado precisa ser uma lista, quer dizer que cada elemento dessa lista conterá a quantidade do respectivo nome? Por exemplo, no seu caso deveria ser `[2, 2, 1, 2]`?

Comment: Isso @hkotsubo, a saída dele tem que ser assim mesmo.

Comment: https://ideone.com/GuRWnu

Answer (score 0):

Há um método em Python que se chama count, ele retorna pra gente o número de ocorrências em uma determinada lista. Nesse caso, poderíamos fazer da seguinte forma:

```
nomes = ['Joao', 'Roberto', 'Pedro', 'Antonio']

def contador(nomes):
    for nome in nomes:
        r = nome.count("o")
        print(f'A letra "o" se repete {r} vezes no nome "{nome}"')

contador(nomes)
```

Answer (score 0):

Tem dois jeitos de fazer.

O primeiro é como @Ale Costa mostrou. Mas, acho que você não só queria a frequência da letra 'o' em **cada** palavra, mas na **lista intera**, certo?

```
def contador(nomes):
    conta_o = 0
    for nome in nomes:
        conta_o += nome.count('o')
    return conta_o
```

Mas, o que eu faria é juntar todos e fazer a conta uma vez, assim:

```
def contador(nomes):
    todos_nomes = ''.join(nomes)
    return todos_nomes.count('o')
```

Ou, ainda mais breve:

```
print(f"Quantidade de vezes que a letra o apareceu: {''.join(nomes).count('o')}")
```